# Including install.img in CentOS 6.2 custom image

Tags: centos, iso-image

I'm creating a custom image of CentOS 6.2 with an automated kickstart installation based on `CentOS-6.2-i386-netinstall.iso`. I've successfully created an ISO image that boots the installer, but it seems to download `/install.img` every time, even if the file exists on my ISO.

The original netinstall image seems to contain `images` and `isolinux` directories in its root, and replicating this on my custom image doesn't seem to work (as in, the installer always downloads the file from a mirror). Where should the `install.img` file be located or is this some forced behavior of the netinstall image?

I tried including the `images` directory within the `isolinux` as well, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

This is what I'm including in the ISO:

```
# ls -lR
.:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Oct 26 00:43 images
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Oct 25 23:41 isolinux
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  912 Oct 25 23:13 ks.cfg

./images:
total 132524
-r--r--r--. 1 root root       442 Oct 26 00:43 TRANS.TBL
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 135696384 Oct 26 00:43 install.img
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root      4096 Oct 26 00:43 pxeboot

./images/pxeboot:
total 32236
-r--r--r--. 1 root root      441 Oct 26 00:43 TRANS.TBL
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 29189501 Oct 26 00:43 initrd.img
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3811616 Oct 26 00:43 vmlinuz

./isolinux:
total 32584
-r--r--r--. 1 root root     1996 Oct 25 22:36 TRANS.TBL
-r--r--r--. 1 root root     2048 Oct 25 22:36 boot.cat
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       84 Oct 25 22:36 boot.msg
-r--r--r--. 1 root root      142 Oct 25 22:36 grub.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 29189501 Oct 25 22:36 initrd.img
-r--r--r--. 1 root root    24576 Oct 25 23:42 isolinux.bin
-r--r--r--. 1 root root     1005 Oct 25 22:38 isolinux.cfg
-r--r--r--. 1 root root   151230 Oct 25 22:36 splash.jpg
-r--r--r--. 1 root root   162860 Oct 25 22:36 vesamenu.c32
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3811616 Oct 25 22:36 vmlinuz
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to edit `isolinux/isolinux.cfg` for that.

If it doesn't help, why don't you base your custom ISO off an ordinary `CentOS-6.2-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso`? It seems to be closer to what you seem to want to do. If I understand correctly, you want to create a CentOS installation ISO without all the RPMs. If it's the case, in your kickstart file, add `--url ...` option to the `install` clause.

Edit: just to clarify the above, I think that the correct way to do this is to use an ordinary .ISO (i.e. not netinstall) and strip all the RPMs from it. I think (not sure) that the netinstall inherently downloads the `install.img`, while an ordinary installation ISO doesn't.

Comment: Yes, netinstall is an image without the RPMs. I already use the --url setting, and that seems to cause the install.img download. isolinux has nothing that would point to the existing install.img file.